# Error saving data to cache directory (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, file-io

I am trying to save images using the following code:

```
- (void)writeData{

    if(cacheFileName==nil)
        return;
    if(cacheDirectoryPath==nil)
        return;


    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self filePath]]) {        

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 0.9);

        NSError *writeError= nil;

        BOOL didWrite =  [imageData writeToFile:[self filePath] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&writeError];

        if(writeError)
            NSLog([writeError localizedDescription]);

        if(didWrite)
            NSLog(@"image saved");
        else
            NSLog(@"image not saved");


    }
}





 - (NSString *)filePath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *filename = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:cacheDirectoryPath]; 
    filename = [filename stringByAppendingPathComponent:cacheFileName]; 
    NSLog(filename);

    return filename;

}
```

I get an error:

```
2009-06-23 16:39:19.740 XXX[33454:20b] Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)
```

I looked this up and see the error has the following meaning:

```
 NSFileNoSuchFileError = 4,                 // Attempt to do a file system operation on a non-existent file
```

Which doesn't make sense since the file shouldn't exist.

I have tried writing the png representation and using the convenience method:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

I am using similar code to save plists, and they work fine. I am not sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you are saving to some directory inside the cache dir. (cacheDirectory/**cacheDirectoryPath**/filename) has the intermediare dirs been created?

Comment: No, isn't that created automatically?

Comment: I don't think so. Try removing the intermediate path and see what happens...

Comment: Thanks! That was it, if you want o post this as an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: i had the same error, but for me it was that i was calling the saveToURL in uidocument to fast.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I see that you use some intermediate directory within the Cache Directory, are it/they created? If not try removing them or use

```
-[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]
```

to create them before