# download images from dropbox in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to download images from dropbox in iOS app. I am getting error as follows:

> [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/dropboxeditimagemarvel.png - (400) Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto', got u'dropboxeditimagemarvel.png'

In AppDelegate.m:

```
DBSession* dbSession =
    [[DBSession alloc]
      initWithAppKey:@"23a9qum6roclx38" // add here app key
      appSecret:@"nh04ru3g53kgzat"  // add here app secret key
      root:kDBRootDropbox];// either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
```

In UIViewController.m

```
[restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata
 {
    if (metadata.isDirectory)
    {
        NSArray *validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jpg", @"jpeg", @"png", nil];
        NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
            NSLog(@"%@", file.filename);
            NSString* extension = [[file.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];
            if(![file isDirectory] && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension]!=NSNotFound) {
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory
                NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"/dropbox/" stringByAppendingString:@"example.png"]];
                NSError *error;
                 [restClient loadFile:file.filename intoPath:filePath];
                }
        }
    }
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client
loadMetadataFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error loading metadata: %@", error);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NSString *)localPath
       contentType:(NSString *)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    NSLog(@"File loaded into path: %@", localPath);
}
```

Please help me..Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but in the `loadFile` call, do you want `file.path` instead of `file.filename`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..  I have done changes suggested by you.. but facing another error as .....:  [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/dropbox/addtextmarvel.png - (4) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0xb3411e0 {path=/addtextmarvel.png, destinationPath=/Users/ruchapande/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/4FDD65E8-0443-4239-894F-14F028A74340/Documents/dropbox/example.png}

Comment: [ERROR] DBRequest#connectionDidFinishLoading: error moving temp file to desired location: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question, since this is an unrelated issue. But take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035092/error-saving-data-to-cache-directory-iphone. The answer there seems relevant.

Comment: just added code below and its working fine in the method: 
 NSString *DocumentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *destPath = [DocumentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file.filename];
                [restClient loadFile:file.path intoPath:destPath];